# Errors with multithreading in for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to add a simple for loop with threads, yet still something is not working out. I've checked a number of reasons and I cannot find any solution to that.

I have a simple class with two methods `A()` and `B()`. From the other class, I'm calling method `A()`. This is how it looks:

```
void MyClass::A()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&MyClass::B, this));
    }
    for(auto &t : threads)
    {
        if(t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
}

void MyClass::B()
{
}
```

And yet I am still receiving some errors:

```
#0 ??   ?? () (??:??)
#1 00446D62 pthread_create_wrapper () (??:??)
#2 75327FB0 msvcrt!_cexit() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#3 040C8710 ?? () (??:??)
#4 753280F5 msvcrt!_beginthreadex() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#5 75B17C04 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll:??)
#6 77ABAB8F ?? () (??:??)
#7 77ABAB5A ?? () (??:??)
#8 ??   ?? () (??:??)
```

Does someone have any idea what is wrong?

Just to add one more thing. This:

```
void MyClass::A()
{
    std::thread t(&MyClass::B, this);
    if(t.joinable())
        t.join();
}

void MyClass::B()
{
}
```

works without any problems.

Comment: @davmac I also was thinking about it, taking into account something like `std::move()`, but looking through many examples online and SO posts I think it is possible.

Comment: I would use `threads.emplace_back(std::move(std::thread(&MyClass::B, this)));`

Comment: @davmac, OP is not copying, OP is moving.

Comment: @knivil rather `threads.emplace_back(&MyClass::B, this);`

Comment: @knivil, not neded. If you want to use emplace, do not pre-construct the object.

Comment: @Zereges unfortunatelly still not working.

Comment: The code as posted is correct. Are you sure this is real code? Please provide copy-paste MCVE.

Comment: @SergeyA indeed, I've retracted the comment.

Comment: std::thread is not copyable, only movable. There is no copy constructor,  so that's not the problem.

Comment: Please show how you're calling MyClass::A().

Comment: FWIW using your code with a simple `main` function and appropriate includes works without problem on linux. Suggest you post full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) as also suggested by SergeyA.

Comment: [Related question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143683/about-analyzing-debug-backtrace)

Comment: Why people keep inventing very inefficient wheels? Just take existing implementation of parallel_for from domain experts like the ones implemented in [tag:tbb], [tag:openmp], [tag:ppl]

Comment: @Anton, it's nice that you call yourself a domain expert... but are you sure you are the one?

Comment: @Anton, that's exactly what I am referring too. Well, keep calling yourself an expert :)

Comment: @Anton, because what you are saying is essentially following 'you people are so much inferior to me, you shouldn't roll your own solutiuon, you should use mine, because I am an expert and you can't possibly hope to reach my level'. My experience proved me that usually people with such a mindset happened to be not-so-great experts. Just personal experience.

Comment: Sorry if it makes such impression. I didn't mean 'use mine' (it's not 'mine' anyway) or attract any personal attention. What I know that manual thread management is verbose and inefficient, at least for one obvious reason here and there are libraries which are more efficient implementing this kind of things. @SergeyA

Comment: Code works for me too, with VS 15. May be you have some installation problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using new and a pointer instead of references.

While references are nice, the number of comments illustrate the confusion caused in this case.   How can you prove that the third party library implementation (eg. std) will work the way you are expecting it to?  and across platforms?

If you use:

```
std::vector<std::thread *> threads;
```

and:

```
threads.push_back(new std::thread(&MyClass::B(), this));
```

And of course with a 'delete' when you are done with the thread, then the confusion is eliminated.

Also, the code is loading the SAME instance of the 'A' class onto the array for all threads.  If you use member variables in A within function 'B', without any sort of multithread protection (eg semaphores, critical sections, etc) your code will never work correctly.  Using a 'new' for the thread instance creation avoids the problems that copy constructors or assignment operators cause with the vector class.

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
  public:
    void A() {
      cout << "starting\n";
      cout << "creating threads\n";
      vector<thread*> threads;
      for (int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
        thread * t = new thread(&MyClass::B, this);
        cout << "creating thread "<<t<<" id:"<<t->get_id()<<"\n";
        threads.push_back(t);
      }
      cout << "waiting for threads to complete\n";
      for (thread * t : threads) {
        if (t->joinable()) {
          t->join();
        }
        cout << "destroying "<<t<<"\n";
        delete t;
      }
      cout << "done\n";
   }

   void B() {
     // now it would be very bad if this function used 
     // member variables that are part of this instance of A
     cout << "hello from " << this << "\n";
   }
}; 

int main() {
  MyClass cls;
  cls.A();
  return 0;
}
```